# Which one is at fault, PC or monitor?

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure

When I connect my PC using HDMI (I dont have DP cable but I have tried two HDMI cables) with my monitor which has a vertical line in panel, it says at start up that checking signal then after a while, it says "no signal, entring power saving mode shortly and then monitor turns off" .

Is something wrong with motherboard? It can't be as I purchased it like six months ago. It used to do that before too, but then on its own it started working and now it is doing that again?

Comment: That can be anything from the PC itself, the cable, or the monitor. We cannot tell from your description. Try pairing PC and monitor with known-good counterparts.

Comment: Yea, start swapping parts. Start with the less expensive obvious ones. Or, take the computer to a competent local pc tech.

Comment: It was the moisture on ram sticks.